# How do I reduce my SwiftUI ViewBuilder Layout?

Tags: swiftui

**Scenario:** I've written a complete UISwift application. But I'm starting get strange behavior when running on a DEVICE versus SIMULATOR:

**I get a blank page when attempting to display a View within its own ZStack layer**; where as via Simulator, it works.

**When I break it down to a simple application vs my large application; it works.**

That made me *suspect* that behind-the-scene the ViewBuilder layout is getting too large/complicated.

So I added a debug() to a view to see the mirror of what I got (abridged):

```
ZStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<Group<_ConditionalContent<ModifiedContent<Image, _AspectRatioLayout>, Color>>, _FrameLayout>, _ConditionalContent<Optional<ModifiedContent<VStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<HStack<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Color, _FrameLayout>, _OverlayModifier<ModifiedContent<HStack<TupleView<(Spacer, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _PaddingLayout>, Spacer, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _PaddingLayout>,
 AddGestureModifier<_EndedGesture<TapGesture>>>)>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>>>>, _PaddingLayout>, ModifiedContent<HStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>>, _PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>>, _PaddingLayout>, 
_BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>>, _PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>)>>, _FrameLayout>, Spacer, Optional<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<VStack<TupleView<(HStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<Text>, _PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, Spacer)>>, HStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<Text>, _PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, Spacer)>>, HStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<Text>, 
_PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, Spacer)>>)>>, _PaddingLayout>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>, Spacer)>>)>>, _HiddenModifier>>, VStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<HStack<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Color, _FrameLayout>, _OverlayModifier<ModifiedContent<HStack<TupleView<(Spacer, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _PaddingLayout>, Spacer, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _PaddingLayout>, AddGestureModifier<_EndedGesture<TapGesture>>>)>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>>>>, _PaddingLayout>, ModifiedContent<HStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>>, _PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>>, _PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>>, _PaddingLayout>,
 _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>)>>, _FrameLayout>, Spacer, Optional<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<VStack<TupleView<(HStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<Text>, _PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, Spacer)>>, HStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<Text>, _PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, Spacer)>>, HStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Button<Text>, _PaddingLayout>, _BackgroundModifier<Color>>, _ClipEffect<RoundedRectangle>>, _ShadowEffect>, Spacer)>>)>>, _PaddingLayout>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>, Spacer)>>)>>>, GlobalMembers)>>
    ZStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<Group<_ConditionalContent<ModifiedContent
<Image, _AspectRatioLayout>, Color>>, _FrameLayout>, _ConditionalContent<Optional<ModifiedContent<VStack<TupleView<(ModifiedContent<HStack<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Color, _FrameLayout>, _OverlayModifier<ModifiedContent<HStack<TupleView<(Spacer, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _PaddingLayout>, Spacer, ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<ModifiedContent<Text, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Font>>>, _PaddingLayout>, AddGestureModifier<_EndedGesture<TapGesture>>>)>>, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<Color>>>>>>, _PaddingLayout>, ModifiedContent<HStack<TupleView
```

This may be correct but I can't explain:

1. Why I can't display a view when the code gets large vs a small test application and
2. Why this works in simulator but NOT on a device.

My brain is blank for the moment.

How do I clear up this mess, or is this okay? 
 There's a command that reduces this to a few lines.  
It escapes me.

Comment: Where is the unmirrored code for ViewBuilder

Comment: It's my entire project, composed of tab views, pickers, etc.  Each tab view has a ZStack of other view that are toggled per context.  I also have some linear graphs.

Comment: I'm not sure how you expect this to be debugged. This *"shouldn't"* happen. I don't know - try breaking it down somewhere by wrapping some views with `AnyView` just to see what happens. But beyond that there isn't much that I think could be offered (happy to be wrong).

Comment: This is incredibly frustrating.  It works fine in simulation but it's breaking down on the device.  What would distinguish between a simulator and a device?   I would think the simulator would be the first to go.  I'll have to research Apple if something similar had happened before.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using an iPhone 6s Plus that has the problem.
I was using the iPhone 8 Plus as the simulator.

So I tried the iPhone 6s Plus SIMULATOR and got the SAME problems as the corresponding device.

So apparently, I need a more-modern device for the latest SwiftUI/Combine frameworks.